# Write a Program To Add a Binary

Tags: binary

I'm trying to implement a program to add a Binary.

The code that is displayed results in run time error.

```
class Solution {
    public String addBinary(String a, String b) 
    {
        return Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(a, 2) + Integer.parseInt(b, 2));
    }

}
```

The error:

```
Runtime Error Message:
Line 5: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10100000100100110110010000010101111011011001

Input :a = "11", b = "1"
Output: "100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if the code bellow can help you. It works here

```
   public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     addBinary("11", "1");
    }

    public static void addBinary(String a, String b) 
    {
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(a,2);
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(b,2);

        System.out.println("String to int: "+ value1 + " " + value2);

        String binary1 = Integer.toBinaryString(value1);
        String binary2 = Integer.toBinaryString(value2);

         System.out.println("Your input in binary: "+ binary1 + " " + binary2);

    }
}
```

Comment: The output for this code is :                                                                                       
String to int: 3 1
Your input in binary: 11 1   which is wrong.